# Dataframe Multiplication in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to multiply each cell of the dataframe below by a constant.

**The data frame**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 5 | 8 | 10 |
| 10 | 15 | 3 | 5 |

**The constant**

a=5,b=10,c=7 and d=20

The desired out but is that all cells in the column A be multiplied by constant a, likewise column B be multiplied by b, C by c and D by d and return a pandas dataframe

**Desired Output**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 140 | 50 | 56 | 200 |
| 50 | 150 | 21 | 100 |

I have tried to multiple but I seem not to get a full dataframe multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by an array of constants:

```
# Same as df.mul([a, b, c, d], axis=1)
>>> df * [a, b, c, d]

     A    B   C    D
0  140   50  56  200
1   50  150  21  100
```

The shape of your dataframe and the array are the same, so Pandas can multiply each column.

To be explicit, you can do:

```
>>> df * pd.Series([a, b, c, d], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
     A    B   C    D
0  140   50  56  200
1   50  150  21  100
```

Comment: @BillyOdera. Does it solve your problem?